# Paging & Sorting grids with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm new to MVC, and am not following how you'd do paging and sorting on a grid.  I'm used to using the asp.Net GridView control with an ObjectDataSource pointed at objects in our business layer - and in that case the ODS handles all of the paging & sorting using the methods that our ORM generates on the objects.

I've looked at using the same ORM with MVC - and things work out fine there - i just loop thru the collections to build the table on the page - but without the ODS to handle the paging & sorting, i'm confused as to how I'd handle that.  Would I have a separate controller for the paging and sorting?

I understand that I need to roll my own - but where do I start?  I've created a CustomerController, and a view that displays a table of customers that looks like below - and I want to sort on FirstName or LastName columns.  My Model has a Sort() method on it that'll take a string sort expression in the format that would be used by a GridView/ODS pair.  Would I create a new Action on my CustomerController called Sort, and put an ActionLink in my header?

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LastName) %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your can use the same controller, just add an additional parameter and name it sort. Then check in the controller what value sort has, and sort your data based on that parameter.

Or if you want to do things on the client side, you can use something like [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), a plugin for jquery.

Answer (score 38):

nowadays MVC 3 now has a webGrid out of the box. I know this question is from a while ago, but I ended up on it when looking for something about webGrid. So I thought it should have an answer mentioning the new webGrid.

Here are a few good posts on how to use it:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=615

http://cnug.co.in/blogs/shijuv/archive/2010/10/08/using-the-webgrid-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx

http://www.nickharris.net/tag/webgrid/

It supports sorting, paging and also some Ajax stuff. It can do lot for you already, but you can also specify every separate column separately.

**Update:**
There are also many JavaScript libraries available that can do the table for you. I personally like to use [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). You can feed it an existing html table generated on the server or give it an endpoint where it can retrieve the data (all or just one page).

There are plenty more, just Google around.

Comment: Greate out-of-box functionality, ships with MVC 3, simple to use. Love it!

Comment: Here's another good post on MSDN that has a little more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Answer (score 3):

With MVC you sort of have to roll your own sorting, paging, etc.  I would suggest [YUI DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) or some of the other JavaScript Grids out there.

Also if you find your self doing heavy Data Grid work you may want to take a look at ASP.NET Dynamic Data, it is specifically designed for these types of interactions against ORM's.

Comment: I am going the route of MVC/Dynamic Data hybrid applications at the moment: the mvc stuff for the non-admin pages and the DD for admin pages.

Answer (score 1):

First use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). jQuery is your friend.
Then use this awesome and probably the best Grid control for jQuery [jqGrid](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/index.htm).

In your CustomerController create an action called CustomerData. All interaction with the Grid should point to this action.

Go [here](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for tons of examples on how to use jqGrid.

Comment: jqGrid is javascript dependent. What if you need JavaScript independency?

Comment: Then you will need to build the table your self. I'v built a paging class & a user control you can use if you want.

Comment: For most developers, JavaScript is  a reasonable requirement.

Comment: sorting on the client is horrible in any circumstance. develop good reusable code for server-side paging

Answer (score 0):

We have been using client side control JqxGrid from [JqWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) and much satisfied with its performance related to huge number of records along with paging, filtering, sorting inbuilt within. [Here](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-binding-to-sql-database-mvc4.htm) is an example of binding it within ASP.Net MVC

Comment: please provide some specific details in how to use those controls to fix the specific scenario - thanks