# Client (sorting/paging) grid for asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Anyone know about a client side grid for asp.net mvc? I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177275/grid-controls-for-asp-net-mvc) but I didn't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496470/paging-sorting-grids-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: How did you not find it?  The post you linked to has like 7

Comment: Can you be more specific about paging? Does all of the grid data need to reside on the client and be paged-out by the client, or is it OK for "pages" of data to be requested as-needed from the server by the client?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). Love it!

Comment: Thank you all! I've found some plugins those solved my problems